# binding t to noop still outputs "t will alias td" warning

Tags: configuration, neomutt

I'm having a strange issue setting up neomutt bindings.

I'm trying to set up t + another key to assign tags to messages with notmuch. However, whenever I fire up neomutt, it complains that:

```
binding 't' will alias 'td'   Before,try: 'bind index td noop' neomutt.org/guide/configuration.html#bind-warnings
```

Here's the relevant bit of my neomuttrc:

```
bind index t noop
macro index tx "<modify-labels>!star<enter>" "Toggle 'star'"
macro index tt "<modify-labels>!todo<enter>" "toggle 'todo' tag"
macro index td "<modify-labels>+done -todo" "Mark as 'done'"
```

I've also tried `unbind index t` and since, neomutt suggests adding  `bind index td noop`:

```
bind index td noop
bind index tx noop
bind index tt noop
```

after `bind index t noop`, even though I think it should not be necessary. No matter what, I still get that annoying message whenever I load neomutt.

I should make it clear that after the warning/error message, neomutt proceeds to working perfectly and tags/untags the message correctly.

Could anyone give me a hint as to any potential mistakes in my config?

Answer (score 0):

I had double-sourced the `bindings` file.